# Which delimiter can be used in phpdbg console or how to run multiple commands in one line?

Tags: phpdbg

I want to be able to run something like this:

`clean; run;` or shorter (`X; r`)

`continue; ev $my_var; ev $other_var` or shorter (`c; ev $my_var`)

Or it can be much more complicated one-liner ;)

How can i do this?

Comment: currently only 0A (line feed) supported as separator… wondering, do other debuggers support other separators too?

Comment: @bwoebi i'm not sure this will be a correct example, but for me, mysql client console is nearly perfect interactive shell. It has `DELIMITER` command to change it's value in current session by user. And feature like `pager _less_` which prints the results via PAGER (_less_ for example). Because when you print large object, it's very complicated to read it's content which takes at least 10 pages (screens), shell cool pager like _less_ could help, it's search feature is awesome. I'll be really happy to have those features.

Comment: I see, but the difference between Mysql and PHP is that `;` (except for the rare case where you create stored procedures) isn't needed in queries. In PHP however you might quickly write `ev (function($big){ unset($big["recursive_dep"]); return $big;})($array)` (PHP 7 syntax)… and quickly have some `;` in your code added… mhm… TBH, The only real delimiter is `#` (as it never will be needed in short PHP code because comments). sounds like a great idea. … the pager … you imagine that like `pager ev $big_array` /  `set pager less`? Sounds great… Will have to figure out how that works though ;-)

Comment: @bwoebi, i'm glad to hear this. In addition `set delimiter X` will be cool to have, it would give to user unlimited freedom in customization :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `#` sign as delimiter. Introduced via http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=adcabcc125094dae8fe1b62dca267e3fa302907d. (PHP 7 only)

Example: `ev get_defined_vars() # clean # run`.

Comment: Note that I didn't add a `set delimiter`, but that's only because there's really no other unicode char without special meaning. (especially in `ev`)

Comment: How about php 5.6? Would i be able to use it in 5.6?

Comment: No, I'm not going to add new features in the 5.6 branch. Only 7.0 because it's not yet released, sorry.